# PHP file_get_contents and echo modified meta tags

Tags: php, domdocument, file-get-contents, meta-tags

I send a url with vars to a php script and want that script to return the same html page with modified or created meta tags according to the vars.
All works perfect except the unmodified tags are rendered in the body instead of the head...

here is my script :

```
<?php
$imagetype = 'image/jpeg';
$panourl = $_GET["panourl"];
$snapshoturl = $_GET["snapshoturl"];
$vfw = $_GET["vfw"];
$vfh = $_GET["vfh"];
$pano_html = file_get_contents($panourl); 

$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHTML($pano_html);
$meta_og_img = null;
$meta_og_img_type = null;
$meta_og_img_width = null;
$meta_og_img_height = null;
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {
    if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:image'){ 
        $meta_og_img = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
    if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:image:type'){ 
        $meta_og_img_type = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
    if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:image:width'){ 
        $meta_og_img_width = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
    if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:image:height'){ 
        $meta_og_img_height = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
}

if (is_null($meta_og_img)) {echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$snapshoturl.'"/>'; }
if (is_null($meta_og_img_type)) {echo '<meta property="og:image:type" content="'.$imagetype.'"/>'; }
if (is_null($meta_og_img_width)) {echo '<meta property="og:image:width" content="'.$vfw.'"/>'; }
if (is_null($meta_og_img_height)) {echo '<meta property="og:image:height" content="'.$vfh.'"/>'; }

$before = array($meta_og_img, $meta_og_img_type, $meta_og_img_width, $meta_og_img_height);
$after   = array($snapshoturl, $imagetype, $vfw, $vfh);

$pano_html = str_replace($before, $after, $pano_html);

echo $pano_html->saveHTML();
?>
```

So I load a html page, check if some meta proprety exist and if not create it and then echo the html page back.
Problem is that in the new html generated all the previous meta tags are pushed into the body and not rendered in the head...
Got a clue ?
THX !!!

Comment: If the getAttribute gives nothing - then use setAttribute to create it in the document.

Comment: getAttribute works perfect !
looks like it's str_replace that is the problem, if I remove this part old meta tags are left in the head part ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to use a small bit of XPath to check if the `meta` tags are there.  But the main thing is that just `echo`ing the new tags does nothing about placing them in the document structure.
What I've done is that if the tags don't exist, they are created as a DOMelement, the attributes added and then this new tag is added to the start of the `head` section.

Edit: I've updated the code to modify the meta tag if it exists, or add it if it doesn't.

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$pano_html = <<< HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta property="og:image:type" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
HTML;
$snapshoturl = "http://someurl";

$html = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html->loadHTML($pano_html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($html);

$head = $html->getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
$ogImageMeta = $xp->query("//meta[@property='og:image']");
if ( $ogImageMeta->length == 0 )    {
    $newTag = $html->createElement("meta");
    $newTag->setAttribute("property", "og:image");
    $newTag->setAttribute("content", $snapshoturl);
    $head->insertBefore($newTag,$head->firstChild);
}
else    {
    $ogImageMeta[0]->setAttribute("content", $snapshoturl);
}
echo $html->saveHTML();
```

This sets the output as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <meta property="og:image" content="http://someurl">
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta property="og:image:type">
     <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

This only does the one tag, I hope that the others will be easy enough to replicate from the code.

Comment: THX ! that works, but what would be the code to only modify the content attribute if the meta exist ?

Comment: I've slightly modified the code, if it finds the meta tag you want, it sets the attribute.

Comment: Sorry Nigel , one more question... if in the html loaded there is a meta tag closed this way </meta> I have an error : Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : meta in Entity,...
Is there a way to avoid this error ? THX !

Comment: If you add the call to `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` - should suppress the warning

Comment: That did the trick Nigel !
Now I have another issue on another server (different php version I guess ?) : Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array in... ($ogUrlMeta[0]->setAttribute("content", '');)
Sorry to be so newbee...

Comment: Try using `$ogUrlMeta->item(0)`

Comment: Me again...
On some servers I have a 500 error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function insertBefore() on null ....
Line 26 : $head->insertBefore($newTag,$head->firstChild);
[link](https://viewp.eu/panorama/harkany/harkanyfurdodata/graphics/360imagessnapshot/setmeta.php?panourl=https%3A%2F%2Fviewp.eu%2Fpanorama%2Fharkany%2Fharkanyfurdo.html&sceneview=pano58%2C-84.355%2C20.086%2C81.818&vfw=1024&vfh=575&snapshoturl=https%3A%2F%2Fviewp.eu%2Fpanorama%2Fharkany%2Fharkanyfurdodata%2Fgraphics%2F360imagessnapshot%2Fscreenshots%2F5a00a62ee13e8.jpg)

Comment: You could check for `$head->firstChild` being null, this would mean that there are no children and so you would  just do `appendChild()` instead.

Comment: Thx so much for your help Nigel !
So I tried to check if firstchild is null (I'm a pure newbee in php...) but now I have the same error on appendChild (but only on some servers)
$head = $html->getElementsByTagName("head")->item(0);
$twitterImageMeta = $xp->query("//meta[@name='twitter:image']");
$newTag = $html->createElement("meta");
$newTag->setAttribute("name", "twitter:image");
$newTag->setAttribute("content", $snapshoturl);
if (isset($head->firstChild)) {
    $head->insertBefore($newTag,$head->firstChild);
}
else {
 $head->appendChild($newTag);
}

Comment: It may be better to open up a new question as it becomes complicated to fix problems via comment.

Comment: Sorry, you're right Nigel...
[Here is the new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175869/fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-a-member-function-appendchild-on-null)